# change pivot-center in image. Video Editiing

Tags: animation, video

Using the Video Editing I'm try to animate a picture rotating it. Looks it's only possible with pivot centered. A Youtuber tutorial show someone rotating imagen from the corner... I can't find how change the pivot possition to animate jpgs in Video Editing...  5:15  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_dy4yMSJSw&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=12

Thanks, very much. JR.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the video, I think the rotation happens always using the center of the VSE video output. In the video the overlay image position is such that its lower left corner happens to be roughly at the overall frame center, so rotation seems to happen pivoting on its lower left corner,but is just a coincidence.

**Edit:** The image is not rotated itself. The image has just an offset that moves it to the upper right corned. Another (green) "trasformation" strip is applied to the image, and that green strip is what is rotated.

Her is what I think it happens:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I move image from vse and try and don't work either.

Comment: See above I edited my answer.

Comment: my english not the best sorry.. let me try to understand it. The solution is create a transparent background png file with picture moved out the center.  It's that?  thanks!!

Comment: I added two screenshots, hth.

Comment: thanks for your help but I dont know how create that "offset" green transformation. I ready install the Addon secuencer: vse transform n work good n noyt about the center to rotate image.

Comment: ? no addon is needed...?!? The transformation strip is added by selecting the image strip you wish to transform and then using the VSE menu Add > Effect strip...> Transform. Your original question was about the pivot center, and I cannot expand to other topics. I suggest you to follow some VSE tutorial to understand the basics, or you'll get easily lost, as it's  a bit different from 3D editors, even if it has something in common.