# VSE. I need to rotate image with arbitrary center pivot point that is not in the center of the image

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I know how to rotate with a transform strip, but I need to rotate around an arbitrary point that is not in the center of the image.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible friend, just follow these steps

1. import your image file in Blender VSE
2. click image offset

[image]

3. Another step should be adding your transform strip to it but this is the place where you go wrong so before adding transform strip change these values by the formula -

x dimension =  (video dimension x - file dimension x)/2

y dimension =  (video dimension y - file dimension y)/2

so here my video dimensions are - (1920,1080)

[image]

and my image dimension are - (620,387)

[image]

so I will change these values -
[image]

to x = (1920-620)/2 = 650
   Y = (1080-387)/2 = 347

[image]

so what we did here is all because to put the pivot point of image file in center.

now add your transform strip and rotate

[image]

Now it will rotate from center
you can change the x and Y points of your transform strip to position your image anywhere but do not change the X Y points of original file .....Use transform strip only to position and rotation.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! This is quite a detailed and well written for a first post! Minor issue though, Stack Exchange is a Q and A site, not a forum. While this is a great first answer,  there is no need to write things like "thank you" (or "thanks in advance" or "hello," or really any other similar things). It doesn't *actually* contribute to the post - the answer is just as helpful with or without the "thank you." (Just like "hello" adds basically nothing to a question).

Comment: If speed is more important than accuracy then I suggest grabbing the transform tools addon. Then simply Hit "t" on ur strip to apply the custom transform strip. in your preview window hit g then click and drag the image such that your axis of rotation is the middle of the preview window. Just roughly place it based on those guidelines. Then with the transform strip still highlighted apply a second strip ontop of itself, unfortunately transform tools doesn't facilitate this so you'll have to do the default shift+a method. The axis of rotation is then updated and you can do ur keyframing.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not combine *Position:* and *Rotation:* to get the desired effect? I see that you are using the *Transform* strip, so a rotation such as this is possible. Note how it appears as if it is being rotated around the bottom left corner:

[image]

I did this by using the *Transform* strip with these settings:

[image]

To determine these settings, I first rotated it to the desired angle. I then moved it so that the left bottom corner was in the original spot; so that it looked like a rotation.

**Alternately, you could jump out of the *VSE* to get a more accurate effect.**

In the *3D Viewport*, load your image onto a plane as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il7ajiCepus). Also align the camera as displayed. Next, from camera view, left click on the plane to bring the *3D Cursor* to the point on the plane that you want to rotate around. With the plane selected, key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (yes, really) and select *Origin to 3D Cursor*:

[image]

Lastly, key <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> to rotate your image around the point on just the right axis.

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for your help. Im trying to animating in VSE because rendering is faster. Just try to know the maximum I can get from VSE. Go to  this tutorial and see in the minute 5:18 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_dy4yMSJSw it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of tests with but it doesn't like that is possible. This could maybe be done by editing the curves in the graph editor (which I tried). You could render an animation with the image being shadeless and the background being transparent. There might be a way to do it. Hope I was helpful.

Comment: here a video 5:18 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_dy4yMSJSw dont know how!!

Comment: someone try to explain me how he did that but I cant understand well the steps. Im new in blender he talk about green offset...not idea    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53057/change-pivot-center-in-image-video-editiing

Comment: another way to do it is creating one png image with center placed in the transparent background